# Set content-type of mail message for ical attachment to "text/calendar; method=REQUEST"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, content-type, icalendar

I am trying to send an iCalendar formatted ics file from App Engine using the App Engine mail API. This works great in GMail. However, Outlook doesn't recognise the file, and I believe the issue is that the content-type is set to "text/calendar" and not "text/calendar; method=REQUEST".

I have tried sending mail with telnet with and without "method=REQUEST" to find that Outlook only actions the ics file if this is included. I have checked the headers sent from App Engine, to find that they do not include method=REQUEST and that is why I believe this is the problem.

I have also seen other people report this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359474/send-meeting-invitation-mail-over-google-app-engine) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/8NYV-93YKxg). There is a java solution to the first link, but having now gone through the App Engine mail api with a fine toothcomb I have so far been unable to set the content-type using Python.

I have tried overriding the EXTENSION_MIME_MAP dict:

```
mail.EXTENSION_MIME_MAP['ics'] = 'text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST;'
```

and setting the header myself:

```
message.headers = {'content-type': 'text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST;'}
```

Both were a long shot, and unsurprisingly, neither work.

So how can this be done?

Comment: UPDATE: I contacted google support who confirmed this was not possible. I managed to work around by implementing the SendGrid SMTP API, which actually works a treat.

Comment: Did you find any other way of sending email from appengine for python apart from send_mail? I need to send .ics files but apart from Yahoo no one is recognizing the invite in the browser. And I really want to use some native service to AppEngine rather than paid third party ones. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible using app engine native apis. Use sendgrid - since I set it up, I have to say that it's worked flawlessly. And they also have quite a generous free tier. I've been quite impressed with the service. I'd recommend at least giving it a try, it's easy to integrate with App Engine.

Comment: Didnt see their free tier, will surely give them a try. Thanks especially for the prompt reply.